# Open3d: color per triangle?

Tags: rendering, mesh, open3d

For a diagram-like rendering in Open3d, I would like to use color per triangle. Open3d normally interpolates per-vertex color (via `open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.vertex_colors`). But this [comment](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/1087#issuecomment-1222782733) suggests per-triangle support was added by December 2021. If so, I am unable to get it to run. This Python test code:

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

def face_color_test():
    mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_octahedron()
    rgb = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
    face_colors = o3d.utility.Vector3iVector(np.array(rgb, np.int32))
    mesh.triangles["colors"] = face_colors
    mesh.compute_vertex_normals()

    # Create a visualization window, add mesh, render.
    vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
    vis.create_window()
    vis.add_geometry(mesh)
    vis.run()
    vis.destroy_window()
```

gets an error on `mesh.triangles["colors"] = face_colors`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cwr/Documents/code/flock/flock.py", line 158, in <module>
    face_color_test()
  File "/Users/cwr/Documents/code/flock/flock.py", line 133, in face_color_test
    mesh.triangles["colors"] = face_colors
TypeError: __setitem__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: open3d.cpu.pybind.utility.Vector3iVector, arg0: int, arg1: numpy.ndarray[numpy.int32[3, 1]]) -> None
    2. (self: open3d.cpu.pybind.utility.Vector3iVector, arg0: slice, arg1: open3d.cpu.pybind.utility.Vector3iVector) -> None
```

I am using one of the workarounds discussed on that GitHub Issue. But if there is a supported way to apply face colors directly I would prefer to use that. Any suggestions?

(I would expect the color data to be rgb triples of floats, but changed it from `Vector3dVector` to `Vector3iVector` based on the error message. I also tried `o3d.core.Tensor(...)` as suggested in the GitHub Issue, but got the same error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the largely undocumented distinction between the “legacy” and “tensor” parts of Open3D.

The color-per-triangle support (and many other features) are in the [open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh) but **not** in the [open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html). The key bit is that subtle **.t.** in the class name.

There is some additional description of this distinction in [Open3D issue #6060](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/6060)